# Induced homomorphism in homology between Moore spaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I am searching for the homomorphism induced $x_{*}: H_{2}(M) \rightarrow H_{2}(N)$ by the maps given in the following proposition:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1-I have found this question [Moore space, induced map in homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091709/moore-space-induced-map-in-homology) here on this site, does that means that the induced homomorphism I am searching for does not exist?

2- Also, is it correct to describe $x$ as a map(the author of the paper did this)?If not, how can I describe $x$ correctly? one of my professors told me that $x$ is not a map it is a universal quantifier.

**EDIT:**

**I want to understand in general what is the case in which we can say there is no induced homomorphisms between more spaces, could anyone help me answer this question please? **

Comment: I may just be unfamiliar with this area of homotopy theory, but I feel like this question is lacking a lot of context. On the other hand, according to the definition quoted in this question, $x$ is some homotopy class of map $M$ to $N$, and therefore induces a homomorphism $x_*$ on homology. I have no idea what you mean by $x$ except for the quoted definition, so it seems like a map to me. 

Also if you're asking what $x_*$ is, that would I presume depend on which $x_{r,k}$ we are talking about, and what $\lambda$ and $i'\phi q$ are. OTOH this isn't one of your two listed questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a co-H-group and $\alpha,\beta:X\rightarrow Y$ are (homotopy classes of) maps then the sum $\alpha+\beta:X\rightarrow Y$ is defined with the co-H-structure on $X$ and the induced map in homology satisfies
$$(\alpha+\beta)_*=\alpha_*+\beta_*.$$
The element $r\cdot \alpha$ for $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ is obtained as the composite
$$r\cdot\alpha=\alpha\circ\underline r$$
where $\underline r\in[X,X]$ is $r$-times $id_X$. Since the map $\underline r$ induces multiplication by $r$ on $H_*X$ we get
$$(r\cdot \alpha)_*=r\cdot \alpha_*.$$

Having covered the relevant background lets address your question. I'm going to have to guess at what the notation means since you haven't included any details for me to go by. Thus I'm assuming that $M=M(\mathbb{Z}_m,2)$ is the fixed space $S^2\cup_{\underline m}e^3$ where $\underline m:S^2\rightarrow S^2$ is as above, that $i':S^2\hookrightarrow M$ is the inclusion of the bottom cell, that $q:M\rightarrow S^3$ pinches to the top cell, and that $\phi\in\pi_3S^2$ is the Hopf map.

Then from the discussion above we get
$$(r\lambda+k(i'\phi q))_*=(r\lambda)_*+(k(i'\phi q))_*=r\cdot \lambda_*+k\cdot(i'\phi q)_*=r\cdot \lambda_*$$
since $\phi_*$ is zero for degree reasons.

Comment: Skimming the paper from which the proposition is copied, it seems that $\lambda_* = \frac{n}{d}$.